# WCF: How do I access a Database from within a Thread using Windows Authentication?

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, iis, windows-authentication

We use a WCF service (hosted on IIS, as part of a C# Silverlight project, using Windows Authentication to log in).

I want to start a thread to do time consuming processing, and it should periodically update the database. With "time consuming" I mean at least a couple of minutes, but always less than an hour. I don't want to risk the async server call timing out.

The problem is that we use Windows Authentication, and once the process enters the thread it appears to lose context and fails with the following error:

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

I tried using a `BackgroundWorker` to move the DB code to the `ProgressChanged()` and `RunWorkerCompleted()` calls, in a hope that they might join to the original context, but without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my [discussion with codechurn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20522920/371917), here is what worked for me:

The problem is that `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` is correctly set until I enter the thread, and then it is NULL. He urged me not to pass it as an argument for the thread, even though it works.

While searching [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2608216/371917) [answers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentprincipal.aspx), I found something that works. `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity` is set to the current identity, which is either a `WindowsIdentity` or another generic identity. The solution below works even if you do not use windows authentication, in which case there is no need to impersonate.

```
new Thread(Run).Start(...);

void Run(object args)
{
    WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext = null;
    if (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity is WindowsIdentity)
    {
        impersonationContext = (Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity as WindowsIdentity).Impersonate();
    }

    try
    {
        // access the DB as normal
    }
    catch { /* always handle exceptions in threads */ }
    finally
    {
        if (impersonationContext != null)
        {
            impersonationContext.Undo();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your IIS, make a right click on the application pool --> Advanced settings and change the application pool user to a windows user that has access to the database.

An application running on IIS always runs under the user you define there. Therefor your WCF service won't have access to the database because at the moment your IIS Pool uses the user "APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool" that is a local user.

Comment: We have access rights set up in the database per user. I don't want the DB to use the wrong user. Is it possible like this?

Comment: If you call a wcf service, the code on server side will always execute under the user that the application pool uses. I am 100% sure, that you can't pass the calling windows user to the database.

Comment: Our web.config specifies that it must use the client's windows credentials instead of the one in IIS. Your answer applies to the exceptional cases where this fails. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While you can configure the application pool to run as a specific domain user account which has access to the database, keep in mind that the IIS service process will now be running as that user.  Optionally, you can pull the client service credentials and using a WindowsImpersonationContext, establish the database connection using the client credentials.

In your service, you could do something like this:

```
//open a SQL Server database connection using the client credentials 
using (var impcontext = ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
    var dbConnection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=myServer; Integrated Security=SSPI");
    dbConnection.Open();
    impcontext.Undo();
}
```

This assumes that your WCF service is setup as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
        <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
      <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <behaviors/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This is actually what I'm looking for, but the problem is that `ServiceSecurityContext.Current` is NULL once I enter the thread.

Comment: @PeetBrits Do you have anonymous access enabled in IIS on the virtual directory hosting the WCF service?  Is the client configured to send the client credentials?  My guess is that you probably have anonymous access enabled and the null ServuceSecurityContext.

Comment: ServiceSecurityContext is only NULL inside the thread. I suppose I can pass it as an argument...

Comment: You should not be passing `ServiceSecurityContext`; rather, WCF sets this up for you when it creates an instance of the service.  If it is null, the client is not authenticated, as I previously mentioned MAKE SURE that anonymous access to the WCF service is turned off in IIS and Windows Authentication is configured correctly.  It sounds like this is a configuration issue.  For more information on `ServiceSecurityContext` see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicesecuritycontext(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I tried it, but the changes you suggested has no influence on anything. `ServiceSecurityContext` is set and working (by default, so my windows authentication is configured correctly), but the moment I enter the custom thread (which I create from within my WCF service call) then it is NULL. Could you please confirm this behaviour of custom threads in one of your services?

Comment: Use an ImpersonationContext to create the thread (instead of the database call I am doing in the example above). This will cause the thread to run in the context of the user.  You can then freely go about doing a database call or any other operation in the thread impersonating the user.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43098/discussion-between-peet-brits-and-codechurn)