# How Do I Get System Account Permissions or run app with system rules in C#

Tags: c#

I want to remove the sections from the registry System\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB, but i cant delete PROPERTIES (windows10)

```
string user = Environment.UserDomainName + "\\" + Environment.UserName;
RegistrySecurity mSec = new RegistrySecurity();

RegistrySecurity mSec = new RegistrySecurity();

RegistryAccessRule newRule =
new RegistryAccessRule(
user,
RegistryRights.FullControl,
InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit,
PropagationFlags.None,
AccessControlType.Allow);

RegistryKey hkusb = hklm.OpenSubKey(RegistryPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadSubTree);

RegistrySecurity security = hkusb.GetAccessControl();
if (ContainsRule(security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier)), newRule))
{
Console.WriteLine("Access");
Console.ReadKey();
return;
}
security.AddAccessRule(newRule);

hkusb.SetAccessControl(security); <----error here
hkusb.Close();
showKeyTree(hkusb, "+");
Console.ReadKey();
```

this code allows me to delete all sections exept PROPERTIES

i understand that iam need to get a system permissions to do this, but i dont know how to make it in code.
p.s.
I need to start process as system
like PsExec, but in code

Answer (score 0):

1. Start this code in new impersonate thread with admin privileges: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608194/how-do-i-start-a-thread-in-a-different-security-context)
2. Impersonate current thread with admin privileges: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net)