# Unauthorized error in c# while on background thread

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, threadpool

I have created an ASP.NET web application in which a file needs to be deleted. Below is the code that performs this operation perfectly

```
File.Delete(path);
```

However when i tried to do this operation on a background thread like this

```
Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path));
```

Then it throws an exception that access to this path is denied. I have tried giving IIS_IUSRS and IUSR full access to the path, but still the error persists. Can someone explain what's going on here. Howcome the file was getting deleted with the first code i.e. on main thread, but not on background thread. Do backgroung threads in C# run with different Identity?

Comment: Keyword here is the thread pool

Comment: After `Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path));` do you something else with the file? Your are not waiting for the Task to finish. If another thread started accessing the file.......

Comment: @PeterBons No after this point, file is not used at all. That's why we decided to delete it.

Comment: await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path));

Comment: @hugorgor we don't want to await this call. The reason is we don't really care the result of this task very much. However, let me assure you that the behaviour is same irrespective of whether we use await or not.

Comment: Do you leave your controller after this call?

Comment: @hugorgor no. There are some string manipulations before that.

Comment: How you seen [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User)? Also your question is [possibly duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2608194/how-do-i-start-a-thread-in-a-different-security-context).

Comment: Down voters,  kindly leave a comment

Answer (score -2):

The main difference between two approaches you provided is that `File.Delete(path)` calls WinAPI function `DeleteFile` immediately, and `Task.Run(() => File.Delete(path))` does the same with some delay.

Something can happen during this short period of time. E.g. Windows Search service can open file for indexing, antivirus can open file for analysis, or some other process can do something with this (I assume) newly created file.

If you are sure that your application doesn't reopen this file later and doesn't hold file handle anywhere, I recommend to use multiple attempts to avoid such issues:

```
Task.Run(() =>
{
    const int attemptsNum = 10;
    for (int attempt = 0; attempt < attemptsNum; attempt++)
    {
        try
        {
            File.Delete(path);
            break;
        }
        catch
        {
            if (attempt == attemptsNum - 1)
            {
                throw; // or log exception here
            }
            else
            {
                await Task.Delay(500);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: This will have an adverse effect on application's performance.

Comment: Are you sure this effect is even tangible? We are talking about some milliseconds per file maximum. How many files per second do you expect to be deleted?

Comment: 1 file per user per every request to that action method. And let me tell you why you were downvoted. If the file gets deleted in the very first iteration, then you will get an exception for the remaining 9 iterations and then every time you will wait for half a second. This way you will end up unnecessarily waiting for about 4-4.5 sec everytime you try to delete the file. Since your threads will be used in this task, less and less threads will be available in the thread pool and will affect scalability.

Comment: Also controlling application flow using exceptions is very bad practice.

Comment: I obviously just forgot to add `break` after `File.Delete(path)`. Fixed.

Comment: If exception will be fired for every file, you should definitely spend some additional time trying to understand what exact process/thread has an open handle for that file. If it will be fired occasionally, catching it won't be a problem from performance point of view. Also note that I proposed to use `await Task.Delay(500)`, so no thread pool threads are taken while waiting.

Comment: It's very disappointing when people downvote without giving any better alternative.

Comment: Yeah it's very disappointing. But if i knew of an answer, i wouldn't have posted the question here.