# Running Window With Other Credentials

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to launch another window in C#/WPF with different credentials.

```
var OpenInterface = new UserInterface();
OpenInterface.Show();
```

Is the execution of this command with different credentials possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you need to impersonate and do the processing

Please do refer the sites shown below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext.aspx

[Can a Thread be executed as another user? (.NET 2.0/3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/730206/can-a-thread-be-executed-as-another-user-net-2-0-3-5)

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User

Comment: Thank you this helped, however i still cannot get authenticated through ad. but good starting point.